# Swipe detection and Touch listener not working inside fragment

Tags: java, android, kotlin

App has bottom navigation menus and fragments. This is the fragment which requires swipe detection similar to Tinder:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {
private lateinit var homeViewModel: HomeViewModel

override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    homeViewModel =
            ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeViewModel::class.java)
    val root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    val textView: TextView = root.findViewById(R.id.text_home)
    homeViewModel.text.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        textView.text = it
    })
    root.setOnTouchListener(object : OnSwipeTouchListener(requireContext()) {

        override fun onSwipeRight() {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Swiped right!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        override fun onSwipeLeft() {
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Swiped left!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    })
    return root


 }
}
```

The app needs Swipe features like Tinder.
Following is the Listener class:

```
open class OnSwipeTouchListener(ctx: Context) : OnTouchListener {
val gestureDetector: GestureDetector

companion object {

    private val SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100
    private val SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100
}

init {
    gestureDetector = GestureDetector(ctx, GestureListener())
}

override fun onTouch(v: View, event: MotionEvent): Boolean {


    var isTouch = false

    if (gestureDetector != null && event != null) {

        isTouch = gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event)
    } else {
        isTouch = true
    }

    return isTouch

}

inner class GestureListener : SimpleOnGestureListener() {

    override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        return false
    }

    override fun onFling(e1: MotionEvent?, e2: MotionEvent?, velocityX: Float, velocityY: Float): Boolean {
        var result = false
        try {


            val diffY = e1?.y?.let { e2?.y?.minus(it) }
            val diffX = e1?.x?.let { e2?.x?.minus(it) }

            if (diffX != null && diffY != null) {

                if (abs(diffX) > abs(diffY)) {
                    if (abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                        if (diffX > 0) {
                            onSwipeRight()
                        } else {
                            onSwipeLeft()
                        }
                        result = true
                    }
                }
            } else {
                onSwipeRight()
                result = true
            }
        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }

        return result
    }


}

open fun onSwipeRight() {}

open fun onSwipeLeft() {}

open fun onSwipeTop() {}

open fun onSwipeBottom() {}

open fun onSwipeDown() {

    }
}
```

The swipe feature or any sort of touch listeners are not working at all. Why is this happening? I'm new to Kotlin and mobile app development. So any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Android, a gesture is defined as the beginning of ACTION_DOWN and ending with ACTION_UP. If you want your view to receive a gesture, you **MUST** return true for ACTION_DOWN, otherwise, you will got nothing.

**Root cause**

```
override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return false
}
```

Because in this callback, you return false, that means your view does not show interest to any gesture, it explains why all callback such as `onFling(), onSwipeRight(), onSwipeLeft()` is not called.

**Solution**

Return true for the ACTION_DOWN event.

```
override fun onDown(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    return true
}
```

[Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EZAoJU-nUyI) is a great article about the Android Touch System. Please take a look when you have time.